# NumPy: Find indices where running total exceeds a value

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of numbers:

```
>>> x
array([20, 20,  1,  3, 13, 20, 25, 20, 10,  9, 20])
```

I want to find the indices where a running total of x exceeds 15, with the total reset each time it exceeds 15.  So for the example data above, it should give:

```
>>> tot_indices(x)
array([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10])
```

At the moment, I'm doing this:

```
cumulative_total = np.copy(x)
ii = 0
cum_tot = 0
while ii < len(accum_spaces):
  cum_tot += x[ii]
  cumulative_total[ii] = cum_tot
  if cum_tot >= 15:
    cum_tot = 0
  ii += 1
indices = x[np.where(cum_tot >= 15)]
```

This works, but does NumPy have a built-in way of doing this that avoids the Python loop?

Answer (score -1):

You could simplify your code using [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)

```
cumulative_total = np.cumsum(x)
indices = x[np.where(cumulative_total >= 15)]
```

Comment: `numpy.cumsum` is not equivalent to the code I've given and doesn't produce the desired output.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry :/